# JWT(lcobucci/jwt) - refresh token

Tags: token, jwt

I am able to generate the token and validate it.

Now, I come across a scenario: *How can I keep the active user's token refresh everytime it send request to server? Rather than suddenly logout them out after the default token's expiration time.*

As per lcobucci suggestion, regenerate the token in every request make by the user.  Meaning the Web/MobileApp have to update the new token in local which return from API in each request?

Any other suggestion/approach I should look into?

I am using it for Mobile and Web apps.

Thanks